# Processing a batch of request with Reactive Extension

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I'm learning Reactive Extensions, and I've been trying to find out if it's a match for a task like this.

I have a Process() method that processes a batch of requests as a unit of work, and invoking a callback when all requests have completed.

The important thing here is that each request will call the callback either synchronous or asynchronous depending on it's implementation, and the batch processor must be able to handle both.

But no threads are started from the batch processor, any new threads (or other async execution) will be initiated from inside the request handlers if necessary. I don't know if this match the use cases of rx.

My current working code looks (almost) like this:

```
public void Process(ICollection<IRequest> requests, Action<List<IResponse>> onCompleted)
{
    IUnitOfWork uow = null;
    try
    {
        uow = unitOfWorkFactory.Create();

        var responses = new List<IResponse>();
        var outstandingRequests = requests.Count;
        foreach (var request in requests)
        {
            var correlationId = request.CorrelationId;
            Action<IResponse> requestCallback = response =>
            {
                response.CorrelationId = correlationId;
                responses.Add(response);
                outstandingRequests--;
                if (outstandingRequests != 0)
                    return;

                uow.Commit();
                onCompleted(responses);
            };

            requestProcessor.Process(request, requestCallback);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        if (uow != null) 
            uow.Rollback();
    }

    if (uow != null) 
        uow.Commit();
}
```

How would you implement this using rx? Is it reasonable?

Note, that the unit of work is to be committed synchronously even if there are async requests that have not yet returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach to this is two-step.

First create a general-purpose operator that turns `Action<T, Action<R>>` into `Func<T, IObservable<R>>`:

```
public static class ObservableEx
{
    public static Func<T, IObservable<R>> FromAsyncCallbackPattern<T, R>(
        this Action<T, Action<R>> call)
    {
        if (call == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("call");
        return t =>
        {
            var subject = new AsyncSubject<R>();
            try
            {
                Action<R> callback = r =>
                {
                    subject.OnNext(r);
                    subject.OnCompleted();
                };
                call(t, callback);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Observable.Throw<R>(ex, Scheduler.ThreadPool);
            }
            return subject.AsObservable<R>();
        };
    }
}
```

Next, turn the call `void Process(ICollection<IRequest> requests, Action<List<IResponse>> onCompleted)` into `IObservable<IResponse> Process(IObservable<IRequest> requests)`:

```
public IObservable<IResponse> Process(IObservable<IRequest> requests)
{
    Func<IRequest, IObservable<IResponse>> rq2rp =
        ObservableEx.FromAsyncCallbackPattern
            <IRequest, IResponse>(requestProcessor.Process);

    var query = (
        from rq in requests
        select rq2rp(rq)).Concat();

    var uow = unitOfWorkFactory.Create();
    var subject = new ReplaySubject<IResponse>();

    query.Subscribe(
        r => subject.OnNext(r),
        ex =>
        {
            uow.Rollback();
            subject.OnError(ex);
        },
        () =>
        {
            uow.Commit();
            subject.OnCompleted();
        });

    return subject.AsObservable();
}
```

Now, not only does this run the processing async, but it also ensures the correct order of the results.

In fact, since you are starting with a collection, you could even do this:

```
var rqs = requests.ToObservable();

var rqrps = rqs.Zip(Process(rqs),
    (rq, rp) => new
    {
        Request = rq,
        Response = rp,
    });
```

Then you would have an observable that pairs up each request/response without the need for a `CorrelationId` property.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This helps very much, indeed! Thanks for a very elaborate answer. The only thing that I can't really get my head around here is, how do I "do something" when all requests have been responded? After the zip how do I say: And now with all request being responded, call these this method with these request/response pairs... I have tried to subscribe to the "rqrps" observable, collect the responses in a list and call a method on completion, but with no success (and it seems a little odd to collect the responses in a list after all this  too). I'd really appreciate some hints on that :)

Comment: @asgerhallas - You shouldn't need to wait for all of the pairs to come back - just start processing them as they come back. Otherwise look at the `.ToArray()` observable operator - it turns `IObservable<T>` into `IObservable<T[]>` - making an observable of n values into an observable of one array with n elements and only on success. Sounds like the perfect operator for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a http request waiting for the collected responses, so there is not that much processing to do (though I could begin to stream them down I guess). .ToArray() sounds just right, I'll check it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the genius of Rx, as you're free to return results either synchronously or asynchronously:

```
public IObservable<int> AddNumbers(int a, int b) {
    return Observable.Return(a + b);  
}

public IObservable<int> AddNumbersAsync(int a, int b) {
    return Observable.Start(() => a + b, Scheduler.NewThread);
}
```

They both have the IObservable type, so they work identically. If you want to find out when all IObservables complete, Aggregate will do this, as it will turn 'n' items in an Observable into *1* item that is returned at the end:

```
IObservable<int> listOfObservables[];

listObservables.ToObservable()
    .Merge()
    .Aggregate(0, (acc, x) => acc+1)
    .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine("{0} items were run", x));
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Now I wonder, what's the easiest way, if I should take the current requestProcessor.Process() that takes a callback and convert the invocation of that callback to what is being observed?

Comment: Oh... found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827178/using-rx-framework-for-async-calls-using-the-void-asyncmethodactiont-callback. It seems like the right direction.